# Аналог до "і глядят унило голиє кусти"

Tags: from-russian, фразеологізми

Щойно подивився на дошку із завданнями для своєї команди і згадався мені рядок із російського вірша:

> і глядят унило голиє кусти

А який/які українські вірші мені могли б спасти на думку? Щоб краще розумівся контекст додам, що мова не про відсутність завдань, а про те, що завдання такі нудні, що краще б їх не було.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Може, якось так:

> [Ізнов нудьга, непрохана кума!](https://www.myslenedrevo.com.ua/uk/Lit/S/Starycky/Poetry/IznovNudgaNeproxanaKuma.html)
>   І серце буцім жде якоїсь-то отрути…
>   Мовчи, бездольнеє! Недовго нам тягнути,
>   Доплентались, що й світла вже нема!
>
> <…>
>
> (М. Старицький)

Answer (score 3):

Також може підійти уривок з [понурого віршика](http://abetka.ukrlife.org/skyba.htm) Романа Скиби:

> Плаче свинка - все намарно.
>   **Всюди сум і в небі хмарно.**